# Twitter API: How to parse URL's out of the text of the tweet using the given list of API's

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

So I'm working with Python and the Twitter API, using Tweepy and Twitter's Stream API, which returns Tweet objects in real-time. Part of my app which queries a different API doesn't play nice with URLS in the tweet text, so I'm using the Python `re` module to replace them with a harmless identifier string. However, I'm having trouble finding the urls that need to be parsed out of the text. Instead of having to search through the text myself for URLS, I decided to use the ones that the API delivers and do a "find and replace" in the text.

[Here is](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects#urls) the documentation on what the API gives me. It gives a t.co url, a display url, and a fully expanded url. The problem with just using the t.co url is that twiter doesn't automatically convert all urls in tweets to t.co, only ones past a certain length. This means that the t.co url isn't always the same one that appears in the tweet text.

So I need to figure out how to get, from the API, the version of the URL which actually appears in the text of the tweet.

Thanks!
evamvid

Comment: Having your code would be a little bit more helpful and show us what it's outputting as it is. Also, does this mean you're having problems extracting `"display_url"`?

Comment: No. I can get "display_url", but I'm not sure if thats the version of the url in that appears in the tweet.

Comment: Right now, the code only outputs `url` because that's what I told it to output. I can get any of the four values; `url`, `display_url`, `extended_url`, and `indices`. I just don't know which to get.

Comment: I understand now, without doing additional modification you'll need the `"url"` field from the json output. That would be your best option.

Comment: Now, I'm thinking using indices may be the best way to do it.....

Comment: Right, but the `url` field gives the t.co link, even when the link in the tweet text hasn't been converted to a t.co link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this for the `extended_url`:

```
tweet_url = str(tweet.expanded_url) # you might not need str(), 
#test it yourself if you'd like.

# Replace tweet by the loop/function you have the json extracted with

tweet_url = tweet_url.replace('\\', '')

print(tweet_url)
```

That should you give you the link without the way you want it.